# Definition $L$ function of elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, l-functions

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve.

My book reads,  we denote '$L$ series of $E$ regrading $l$ adit representation of $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$'  as
$L(E/\Bbb{Q}):=  \prod_{p}\frac{1}{1-a_pp^{-s}+ε_p p^{1-2s}}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{a_n}{n^s}$.
Here, for given $p$, if we admit the former $a_p$ and latter $a_n$ of this equation coincides when $n=p$, we can define '$a_p$ of  $E$' by $L$ series.

I have questions about this definition.

1. What is definition of $a_p$ and $ε_p$ here ? My book does not write about that, but I guess $a_p$ is trace of Frobenius and $ε_p$ is determinant of Frobenius.
2. why the former $a_p$ and latter $a_p$ coincides for all $p$  ?
3. The definition seems to be the same as 'Hasse Weil $L$ function' and $l$ does not appear in the definition above. Why we(the book) calls this $L$ as '$L$ series of $E$ regrading $l$ adit representation of $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$' ?

Comment: If $J$ is of dimension $d$ then $Frob_p$ acts on $J[\ell^\infty]$ (or $T_\ell(J)$ as you wish) as a $GL_{2d}(\Bbb{Z}_\ell)$ matrix but its characteristic polynomial is in $\Bbb{Z}[t]$ and the L-function is $\prod_p \frac1{\det(I- t Frob_p)|_{t=p^{-s}}}$ (up to annoying special case at finitely many bad reduction primes and $p=\ell$..). The form you gave should be when $J$ is an elliptic curve

Comment: thank you so much, I edited.

Comment: So yes $a_p = Tr(Frob_p) = p+1-\#E(\Bbb{F}_p)$ for good reduction $p\ne \ell$. $\varepsilon_p$ is $p = \det(Frob_p)$ unless there is bad reduction. Check that for a $2\times 2$ this is the characteristic polynomial evaluated at $t=p^{-s}$. So it is the Artin L-function of the  Galois representation. What do you mean with "the book doesn't define it"?

Comment: Did you prove the Euler product for $\zeta(s)$? It works similarly here, $\frac1{1-a_p p^{-s} + p^{1-2s}}$ is a power series in $p^{-s}$ and expanding the Euler product gives a Dirichlet series whose $p^{-s}$ coefficient is $a_p$. Motivating the definiton of the Hasse Weil L-function of elliptic curves is notoriously hard.

Comment: Thank you reuns, sorry for delay of my response. The book explains $L$ series without any mention about $a_p$ and $ε_p$.

Comment: For elliptic curve case, I understood the definition. But for general abelian variety case, I think $Frob_p$ might not exists, then what is $a_p$(trace of $Frob_p$)?

Comment: In my understanding, $Frob_p$ is element of $End(A)$ which reduces $q$-th power map on reduction mod prime ideal above $p$.

Comment: No $Frob_p$ is an element of $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$ which acts as the Frobenius $\phi_p$ on $\overline{\Bbb{Z}}/\mathfrak{p}\cong \overline{\Bbb{F}}_p$ for some prime above $p$. When there is good reduction and $p\ne \ell$, the reduction map is an isomorphism $E[\ell^\infty]\to E_{\bmod \mathfrak{p}}[\ell^\infty]$ so $Frob_p$ and $\phi_p$ have the same characteristic polynomial (as endomorphisms of $T_\ell(E),T_\ell(E_{\mod \mathfrak{p}})$). $\phi_p$ is an algebraic endomorphism so its characteristic polynomial is in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Does my Frobenius (lement of $End(A)$ which reduces to $q$-th power map on reduction mod prime ideal above $p$) has the same characteristic polynomial ?  Or my Frobenius have nothing to do with $Frob_p$ and $φ_p$ ?

Comment: Sure if you can show that $\phi_p$ is the reduction of some $f\in End(A)$ (and $p\ne \ell$ and there is good reduction at $p$) then the 3 have the same characteristic polynomial as group endomorphisms of $T_\ell(E)$ and $T_\ell(E_{\bmod \mathfrak{p}})$. This is indeed why CM elliptic curves are so much easier than non-CM ones, we can understand all their reductions just from looking at the factorization of primes in their endomorphism ring.

Comment: Is the book a secret?